# How many forts of Shambara did Indra really destroy?

Tags: rig-veda, indra

Why do these verses of Rigveda contradict each other on the number of Shambara's forts destroyed by Indra? How to reconcile these differences?

**90 forts**.

> Rig Veda 1.130.7 “For Pūru thou hast shattered, Indra **ninety forts**, for Divodāsa thy boon servant with thy bolt, O Dancer, for thy worshipper. For Atithigva he, the Strong, brought Śambara from the mountain down…”

**100 forts**

> Rig Veda 6.31.4 “Thou smotest to the ground **the hundred castles,** impregnable, of Sambara the Dasyu…”
>
> Rig Veda 2.14.6 “Ye ministers, to him who as with thunder demolished Śambara’s **hundred ancient castles…”**

**99 forts**

> Rig Veda 2.19.6 “…And Indra, for the sake of Divodasa demolished Sambara’s **nine-and-ninety** castles.”

Comment: Good question. I am having the same doubt.:-)

Comment: I think the number of forts destroyed should be viewed in esoteric sense only. It may indicate number of obstacles faced by the particular sage and which were removed by the God